# Macbook OSX update 10.6.8 to newer

Tags: osx, macintosh, software-updates

I have my wife's old laptop that has Snow Leopard (10.6.8) on it. Going to backup everything and then fix the trackpad and give it a bit of clean up for her. I am not an advanced or even intermediate mac user but am slowly learning.

I was wondering how to update the OSX to atleast Sierra if possible?

I go to the software update dialog and didn't see any operating system related updates. And when I go to the App store and try to *Get* the High Sierra download it says I require atleast 10.8.0.

Any help on how to upgrade would be amazing! I'm sure there will be a payment necessary but hopefully don't need to buy 10.8.0 and then High Sierra aswell.

**Edit:**
Specs are
Macbook Pro 8.1
Intel Core i5 2.3 GHz (2 core)  Early 2011

Please let me know if there is anything else necessary and will update accordingly.

Comment: What model is it? How old is the hardware? It might get only snow leopard for a reason. It is Intel or PowerPC? How much RAM? You are leaving essential details out of the question.

Comment: Not home to check will confirm but I believe it is an 2011 macbook and almost 100% sure it is intel based. Weird that the High Sierra download comes up in App Store though with the "get" button if it wouldn't work.Edit: Wife is home going to try get her to confirm. Oh didn't know they were essential will update question and let you know once done.

Comment: Updated question. Definitely an Intel based macbook

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is [not about](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) the "Unix foundation underlying OS X". I would recommend reposting on our [Apple sister site](https://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I would upvote if I could too. Didn't notice that in the list! Would be nice if they put Mac or OSX in the description as that is what I searched for first then went to Unix as it is a unix like system.

Comment: No worries, welcome to the StackExchange community, and hopefully you'll find some good answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this site https://support.apple.com/kb/SP765 your model is supported by High Sierra.

You might get lucky downloading the ISO, burning it in a pen or DVD, and booting from it - the 10.8.0 requirement is for upgrading; without it you will have to reinstall everything from scratch.

Be sure to backup everything *before* installing the new version.